# Spring Boot MongoDB - Can't access collection data via ObjectId

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm currently learning how to code my own backend server with Spring Boot. Said server should retrieve values from a MongoDB collection and display them as JSON data inside the browser. So, I initalized myself a template project (not the MongoDB one) with Spring Initializer, added some additional dependencies to the pom file and added the data/mongo dependencies and started to go trough the tutorials. Everything is working fine, except one thing: I can't retrieve any data by their corresponding ObjectId. Before I show you the code, I'll explain you how my environment setup looks like:

Machine: Windows 10 Home Edition 64-Bit

IDE: Eclipse 2019-12 CDT with the Java and M2E plugin as well as the Spring Tools

JDK Version: JDK 13

MongoDB Version: 4.2.3

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybackend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mybackend</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>13</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Person.java**
        package com.example.mybackend;

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Person 
{
    @Id private String Id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getfirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getlastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setfirstName(String updatedfirstName)
    {
        firstName = updatedfirstName;
    }

    public void setlastName(String updatedlastName)
    {
        lastName = updatedlastName;
    }
}
```

**PersonRepository.java**
        package com.example.mybackend;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel="person",path="person")
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person,String>
{
    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

I've excluded the *MyBackendApplication.java* file on purpose due to the fact, that it wasn't modified at any point. My main problem occurs when I make a "GET" request to the URI "http://localhost:8080/person/*ObjectId*" (ObjectId is the _id value inside of MongoDB as a String). The result is a blank webpage and the hint inside my browser that the request for the collection has returned an 404 error. However, according to the tutorials instruction this shouldn't happen. I've also tested the same step with curl without any success.

UPDATE:
I could resolve my issue by changing the identifier of my Id to *id* instead of *Id*. I'll update this response if I get further information.

Comment: You don't have any `ObjectId` because your `_id` is `String` type

Comment: But so is my "Id" inside the Person class. Does the ObjectId inside the URI  gets converted into another object type?

Comment: `@Id private String Id;` inside MongoDB is `_id` (underscore id). When you retrieve person, `_id` (underscore) will be mapped to `id` (no underscore). In MongoDB `_id` field is stored as String if you provide string identifier at least 33 characters. If not, MongoDB will add as ObjectId. but, when you retrieve your person, Spring will map `_id` (underscore id) field into `id` person attribute

Comment: First of all, thank you for the advice so far. I've read the Spring Boot MongoDB documentation extensively and by quoting their own words "A property or field annotated with @Id (org.springframework.data.annotation.Id) maps to the _id field.
". Therefore your answer should be right. However, on my environment it isn't. Sry, I'd really love to mark this comment and/or post as the definitive answer to my question :/